# Help in understanding php links

Tags: php, mysql, database

My website has a structure like this:
root folder contains --- > 1)index.php 
                          2) Child Folder which also contain home.php, contact.php and                products.php

Now I just created a new page called page.php (in the child folder) and made some changes to it so it becomes unique to only the homepage.

My question is, how do I change the the homepage link from the default home.php (in the child folder) to the page.php??

Do I have to create the link in the index.php

---

Please forgive my ignorance. To make the question simple, take it this way: How do I create a theme and make it unique to only a particular page say only the homepage or only the products page?? I've been very frustrated for weeks trying to customize my homepage

Comment: Please post your code and read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: Does renaming page.php to home.php do what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really tell what you're asking. Are you trying to make it so that:

```
http://mywebsite.com/child-folder/
```

Resolves to this?

```
http://mywebsite.com/child-folder/page.php
```

---

If so, just put this in `/child-folder/.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex page.php
```

Comment: Yes sir. By default, my homepage url is http://mywebsite.com/index.php. I didn't like its appearance. So I created a new page called page.php which would rather apepar when someone visits the homepage of my website in place of the index.php

Comment: @user850814: Why not just change index.php if you don't like how it looks? Or do you mean the appearance of the url? Also, I can't believe I clicked that link and expected it to go somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarly for PHP question.

You need to elaborate on your question a bit more. For example, are you trying to go to lets say www.examplesite.com and have it than point to the page.php page and have that be the homepage?

If so, you can do a PHP redirect with

```
header("Location: folder/page.php");
```

That needs to be in the header of the file or what I would do is alter it in .htaccess with RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.exampleurl\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.exampleurl.com/folder/page.php
```

Comment: Please take it this way. I want the homepage to now be page.php instead of the home.php

Comment: Well as mentioned, either of those ways should work. I updated the RewriteRule as I realized that was wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much sir for your effort. I sincerely appreciate that. I followed your instructions but I got this error: "This webpage has a redirect loop" How can I solve it please?

Comment: Oh, duh, that part was my fault. Revised the answer, I think I added the ! by accident to the RewriteCond